# Error occurred during initialization of VM for spring version test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am about to start to learn Spring Framework. For that, I had to set up the runtime environment in which I am having a problem. I have installed java and Spring boot CLI. I had set up all the paths as well. However, I get an error of

An error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: The specified procedure could not be found

whenever I type spring in cmd.

When I google about this problem, I found a whole lot of complex stuff, and I am just beginner. Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, java and maven/gradle are pretty much the Spring Boot starter pack.

There are lots of examples of how to start development with spring boot, especially on the [pivotal](https://spring.io/) site itself.

For example:

1 - [Developing Your First Spring Boot Application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html)

2 - [Building an Application with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Also, i recommend you start first through the [initializr](https://start.spring.io/). Later, you can look for more advanced tools and/or options to manage your project.